# socket hangup / ETIMEDOUT exceptions with nodeJS

Tags: node.js

I realize a great deal has been said on this topic, but I believe I am closing my connections, and would appreciate a new set of eyes to tell me if I am missing something.

- an object containing the request information is created and passed to `throttle`
- `throttle` puts it on a stack and starts an interval timer which calls `process_queue` every 1200ms; `get_info` is passed as the request callback.
- At some point (varies) during execution, **socket hang up** and **connect ETIMEDOUT** exceptions are thrown, at which point I re-queue pending requests, wait a short interval, and start the process_queue again.

This works fine early on, but the occurance of exceptions seems to accelerate over time, and really, they shouldn't be happening anyhow if I am closing them correctly.

Any feedback is greatly appreciated.

```
var timer         = null;
var takeabreather = null;
var stack         = [];
var pendingqueue  = [];

function throttle(item) {
    stack.push(item);
    pendingqueue.push(item);
    if (timer === null) {
      timer = setInterval(process_queue, 1200);
    }
}

function process_queue() {
    var item = stack.shift();
    var req  = http.request(item.opts, get_info);

    req.on('error', function(e) {
        logger.error('--- PROCESS_QUEUE: ERROR: ' + e);
        req.end();
    });

    req.end(function(){
      logger.debug('PROCESS_QUEUE: ENDING...');
    })

    // clear timer is there is no work left to do...
    if (stack.length === 0) {
        clearInterval(timer);
        timer = null;
        logger.info('PROCESS_QUEUE: queue is empty');
    }
}

function get_info(response) {
    var body = '';

    response.on('data', function(d) {
        body += d;
    });

    response.on('end', function() {
        var parsed  = JSON.parse(body);
        var doc     = {};
        parsed.forEach(function (item) {
            try {
                doc.name = item.name;
            }
            catch (err) {
                logger.error('--- GET_INFO ERROR: ', response.req.path, err);
            }
        });
        // code to remove item from pending queue redacted //
        logger.debug('--- GET_INFO END: ', response.req.path);
    });
}

process.on('uncaughtException', function (e) {
  logger.error('--- UNCAUGHT_EXCEPTION: ' + e);
  clearInterval(timer);
  timer = null;
  if (takeabreather === null ) {
      logger.warn('--- REQUEUING...');
      stack = pendingqueue;
      logger.warn('--- TAKING A BREATHER...' );
      takeabreather = setTimeout(process_queue, 10000);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out, I had a nested `http.request` in `get_info` that was not being closed via `.end()`